# Can I use the tag textbox script?

Tags: support, tags, javascript

I love the "Tags" textbox on Stack Exchange. It looks like a hassle and a half to write though, so is there a free "label textbox" scripts I can use?

Alternatively, is the one on Stack Overflow free to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 13):

While we wrote the tag editor from scratch, it's heavily inspired by the ["Chosen" plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Have a look at the "multiple select" examples on that page; it may just be what you're looking for.

Comment: it didn't answer his last question - is the one on stackoverflow free to use?

Comment: I have now written a textbox with the same functionality as the tags textbox (Except the revert back to text when a selection starts). But I'm having one problem: How do you increase the textbox size with the size of newly written characters when you're not using a monospace font? I set it to grow 8 px per character but obviously that only works now and then. Have you hardcoded a size per character or something? Would your textbox work equally well with any font? Thanks for any answers you can provide.

Comment: @genesis: Until stated explicitly otherwise, everything in here belongs to Stack Exchange Inc. ... that's a No, by the way. If part (or even the whole) engine would be freely available, we'd already know.