# What is the control that is being used in the "Tags" section of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the tag textbox script?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510/can-i-use-the-tag-textbox-script)

What is the control that is being used in the Stack Overflow site for the **Tags** sections when you are asking a question.

I need a similar control in my project where the textbox needs to provide with auto suggestions based on user keyin values and also the user will be able to select multiple values from the suggested list. It would be nice if there is an option to delete the selected elements as well. I really liked the control used here in Stack Overflow. So, what is this control? Or will there be any such controls available?

I would prefer jQuery tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Overflow tag system is "heavily inspired" by this plug-in -

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Source - [Can I use the tag textbox script?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510/can-i-use-the-tag-textbox-script)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.How can I get the multiple selected values, when I am trying to say the dropdown selected value..it is always giving me the last selected value..it is not giving me the list of selected values.